# Populating a text filter web part from another list

Tags: list

I'm in the process of creating a Project status Page. On it I put several lists web parts each detailing a different project activity: project description, task, discussions, links for the site. At the top of the page I've put a text filter web part that is connected to by all of the list web parts link to it.  This part all works.

Now I want to be able to select a project and have that pull up the Project status web page and populate the text filter web part so that I get just that project. I realize I could just put each project in the filter web part and save that URL. That defeats the purpose by forcing me to manually do this for each project, there are several hundred projects.

The goal here is to create a project dashboard but then pull up this page to provide more detail.

I'm thinking I can do this with a workflow or some sort of web part link? Any suggestions would be welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Since you said you have filters, I'm going to assume you are using the Enterprise SKU of Sharepoint.  What you could do is to use the Query String filter web part to filter all your web parts.  Then you'd have a landing page or web part that then generates a hyperlink to this page, ex /site/pages/dashboard.aspx?project=123 or /site/pages/dashboard.aspx?project=Johnson.

When configured, the query string filter will grab that parameter, and feed it into all the web parts like your text filter is doing.  If you have a projects list with all the projects, it'd be easy to whip up a little DVWP to build the link list to get to the dashboard.